# Login form with AFNetworking 1.3

Tags: ios, afnetworking, session-cookies, forms

I am trying to login into a website through an HTML form using AFNetworking 1.3. I simply set my credentials and POST to the proper path. The problem is that I am not issued a cookie that states that I am logged in.

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mysite.edu"];
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:baseURL];
NSString *loginPath = @"/place/loginPage";

NSDictionary *loginParameters = @{@"sid" : @"username",
                                  @"PIN" : @"12345678"};

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                 path:loginPath
                                                           parameters:loginParameters
                                            constructingBodyWithBlock:nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success: %@", operation.responseString);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);
}];
[operation start];
```

**The web server is returning a webpage that states that I do not have cookies enabled:**

> This system requires the use of HTTP cookies to verify authorization information.
>                                        Our system has detected that your browser has disabled HTTP cookies, or does not support them.
>                                        Please refer to the Help page in your browser for more information on how to correctly configure your browser for use with this system.

However, if I iterate through my issued cookies, I find that the website has issued me cookies, but not a session cookie. Therefore my AFNetworking client really is accepting cookies? **Is there a setting that I must adjust to allow session cookies to properly work with AFNetworking 1.3?**

I have edited my HTTP request header to match working browsers such as Chrome.

Comment: It may be you need to pass some additional header information so the server believes you can handle cookies.

Comment: I tried your recommendation and imitated all of the HTTP header field that were successfully used in Chrome. Still no luck. It looks like it is setting the session cookie like SESSION=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Is] my AFNetworking client really [] accepting cookies?  Is there a setting that I must adjust to allow session cookies to properly work with AFNetworking 1.3?

AFNetworking has no cookie-specific configuration.  Cookies are solely the responsibility of the [Foundation URL Loading system](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html).

Some possible solutions:

1. Install [`AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger) and configure it with `AFLoggerLevelDebug` to see all HTTP headers.  This will let you see what's actually getting sent and received in your Xcode console.
2. The server may be dropping the cookie, for example if it's a Ruby server with `protect_from_forgery` enabled.  Check your server logs and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20308111/1445366) for information on disabling or sending the appropriate token.
3. You control how requests use cookies with `-[NSMutableURLRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies]`.  Make sure this is set to `YES` (the default.)
4. Other apps can alter the Cookie Accept Policy, so make sure `-[NSHTTPCookieStorage cookieAcceptPolicy]` is returning `NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways` (or `NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyOnlyFromMainDocumentDomain` if you need it.)

Comment: (Summary: the issue is probably that your server isn't sending them, not that AFNetworking is losing them.)

Comment: We decided to go a different (less fragile) route altogether. Thanks anyways for your help

Answer (score 0):

Since I came here while searching for a working solution for ***AFNetworking 2.0***, not knowing that `AFHTTPClient` was removed from the Framework, I will post the new way to establish this connection here:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://examplewebsite.com"]];
[manager setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];
[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"userName" password:@"password"];
```